# Filter a model in using "for" in Django

Tags: python, django, filter, many-to-many

Is there a way to filter when using {% for %} in the template ?
For example I got this:

Models:

```
class Options(models.Model):
    option = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Brand(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField()

class Products(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(Options)
    brand = models.ManyToManyField(Brands)
```

In the template:

```
{% for article in Options %}
    {% for sth in products where type=article.0 %} <--- Is this possible ?
                                                        I need to make it iterable
         //Do something
    {% endfor %}
{% end for %}
```

Is there a way to do it ?
If you dont understand something just ask :)

Comment: Are you looking for the [ifequal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#ifequal) tag or `==` operator?

Comment: No, I'm looking for a filter , like model.objects.filter(field="something"), but that can be used on the template, u get it ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are approaching this from the wrong angle. Logic like that should go in the views.

You seem to wanting to group your products by type, so wherever you specify your queryset in your view for the products, use order by.

```
queryset = Products.objects.filter(filters_here_if_you_need=any).order_by("type__option")
```

Then in your template you will only need the inner loop

```
{% for sth in products  %} 
     //Do something
{% endfor %}
```

Now your products will be ordered by the options.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: Right, but I have a menu that filters by type , so if he clicks type 1 , it only has to show that type and the others, that's what i'm trying to acomplish

Comment: Are you doing the filtering in JavaScript? Or in Django? If its in Django pass the filter to the queryset in the view.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of options actually

```
{% for thing in things %}
    {% for product in products.all %}
        {% if thing.type == product.type %}
            <!-- do stuff -->
        {% else %}
            <!-- pass -->
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% end for %}
```

or

```
{% for thing in things %}
    {% for product in products.all %}
        {% ifequal thing.type product.type %}
            <!-- do stuff -->
        {% else %}
            <!-- pass -->
        {% endifequal %}
    {% endfor %}
{% end for %}
```

You *could* write a [SimpleTag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) to filter your related manager directly in your template, but I wouldn't recommend it. You could also add a property to either of the models that takes an argument and use a simple tag to feed the method in your template.

If your data isn't that dynamic you could also directly return the proper [context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data) to your template.

Comment: It worked, but it doesnt seem to return True even if they are equal , any idea ?